# Explain this equation mathematically

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differentiation, mathematics

$$\Bigl( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \Bigr)_H = \Bigl( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \Bigr)_M + \Bigl( \frac{\partial S}{\partial M} \Bigr)_T \Bigl( \frac{\partial M}{\partial T} \Bigr)_H$$

How can one go from LHS to RHS. I understand chain rule and partial  derivatives but unable to figure out how can this be written. Explanations are welcome!

Comment: Please do not use images/ screenshots but [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Consider $S(T,M(T,H))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with this kind of equations, I like to think of differential forms.

There are essentially two rules that solve most of the problems:

1. Algebraically, you can treat differential $dH$ forms as vectors, i.e. you can add them, multiply by scalars and decompose one form as a linear combination of others.
2. The differential of a function $f$ is a sum of terms: partial derivative $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)_{x_1,\ldots,x_n}$ times the differential of a variable $dx_i$. For example, suppose you want to write a differential of $S(T,H)$. You have:
   \begin{equation}
   dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_H dT + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial H}\right)_T dH
   \end{equation}

Now, you want to find $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_H$. This is simple - you need to decompose $dS$ into a linear combination of $dT$ and $dH$ and whatever stands next to $dT$ is your derivative.

On the RHS you have terms where $S$ is a function of $T$ and $M$, so a good starting point would be
\begin{equation}
dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_M dT + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial M}\right)_T dM.
\end{equation}
And now we only need to get rid of $dM$, so we express it as:
\begin{equation}
dM = \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_H dT + \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_T dH.
\end{equation}
I will let you solve the rest of the problem.

This is probably not as fast as a simple chain rule but gives you a better control of what's happening. I think it allows for easier backtracking of your steps and avoiding silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can deduce the involved functions by looking at terms like $\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}|_M$. This tells you that there is a function $S$ of variables $(T,M)$. Likewise $\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}|_H$. This tells us that there is a function $M(T,H)$.

The equation is then obtained by using the the total differentials of the functions, $$S(T,H), \  S(T,M), \ M(T,H)$$
Expand $dS(T,H)=dS(T,M(T,H))$ and compare the coefficient in front of $dT$. This yields your equation. Alternatively you can take the partial derivative and use the chainrule $\frac{\partial }{\partial T}S(T,H)=\frac{\partial }{\partial T}S(T, M(T,H))$.